# Qt WinRT App cannot access file permission denied

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, windows-runtime

I need to develop WinRT App using Qt and FFMPEG, I build the ffmpeg for WinRT based on the instruction [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop)  and I am able to link the library with my project. Now I need to open a video file using `avformat_open_input` but it always giving me the output

```
video decode error "Permission denied"
```

Below is the relevant part of the code,

```
 int ret = avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, hls, NULL, NULL);
    if(ret != 0)
    {
        char errbuf[128];
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, 128);
        qDebug()<<"video decode error"<<QString::fromLatin1(errbuf);

    }
```

From the above error it seems some permission issue, do I need to add any additional permission on `AppxManifest.xml` currently I am using default manifest which is created by Qt creator.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a file protocol to the manifest page, contains your file extension you want to access/ create or play with..

for example, .xml, .txt, .etc..

I always face this 'unknown' error when try to access files without adding the ext file protocol..

**UPDATE:**
More Information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx#file_activation

Do it by: Package.appxmanifest > Declarations > Add a 'File Type Association' > your type name and ext. is required.

Example in a code:

```
  <Extensions>
    <uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
      <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="myfile">
        <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
          <uap:FileType>.config</uap:FileType>
        </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
      </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
    </uap:Extension>
  </Extensions>
```

Change 'myfile' and '.config'

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please provide me any reference.

Comment: I have added the below code ` <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <FileTypeAssociation Name="filename">
            <DisplayName>DisplayName</DisplayName>
            <SupportedFileTypes>
              <FileType>.mp4</FileType>
            </SupportedFileTypes>
          </FileTypeAssociation>
        </Extension>
      </Extensions>` on manifest file but still the error `Failed to get file URI. (Access is denied.)`

Comment: Are you trying to access a System folder? like Videos Library or the Documents folder? you need a permissions for that in the Appxmanifest (Check it in the capabilities)

Comment: I tried that by adding `<Capabilities>
   <Capability Name="musicLibrary" />
   <Capability Name="internetClient" />
   <Capability Name="videosLibrary" />
   <Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
 </Capabilities>` , Basically what my application do is, user have the option for selecting the video file by browsing, then the application should play that file. Actually to make sure whether  it is permission issue I wrote simple code to create a directory that also gave some error, I posted the question here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560994/qt-winrt-folder-permission-issue