# Qt WinRT Folder Permission Issue

Tags: qt, windows-runtime

Hi I already posted a question [Qt WinRT App cannot access file permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551995/qt-winrt-app-cannot-access-file-permission-denied) regarding ffmpeg library and video file read, and now I think the entire project should have some permission to access/modify the files system in WinRt Qt App.

Below is a simple code which create a directory if not exist, bu this also failing always, so I think it permission issue, and there are something should add on AppxManifest.xml.

```
QString dirname = QDir::homePath()+"/test";
    QDir dir(dirname);
    if(!dir.exists())
    {
        //dir.mkdir(dirname);
        if(false==dir.mkpath(dirname)){
            qDebug()<<"Creating "<<dirname<<" failed...";
        }
    }
```

Anyone have faces this before, any suggestion, tips ..

Thanks in Advance.
Haris

Answer (score 1):

WinRT as a platform will not allow you to "simply" create files outside the sandbox of the application. There are certain directories you can use (Media, Photos, ...) in case you have the correct capability set. And even then you will only be allowed to open/create/read/write files selected by the file picker.

Comment: Do you have a link to a reference and eventually to a ticket of feature request we may follow ?