# UWP C# and Windows Runtime Component C++ Permission Denied error when opening file

Tags: c#, c++, ffmpeg, uwp, windows-runtime

I have developed a UWP app in C# which contains a Windows Runtime Component C++ project. the app allows the user to choose an mp4 file and passes this file to the c++ code, which then utilizes ffmpeg libraries to retrieve the presentation time stamps of a video file and output them to a file.

the issue i'm facing is that the c++ code is not able to open the mp4 file when using the `avformat_open_input` function:

```
int PTSExtraction::parse_file(Platform::String^ filename)
{
    int ret = 0;
    AVPacket pkt = { 0 };


    std::wstring fileNameW(filename->Begin());
    std::string fileNameA(fileNameW.begin(), fileNameW.end());
    const wchar_t* w_chars = fileNameW.c_str();
    src_filename = fileNameA.c_str(); 

    if (avformat_open_input(&fmt_ctx, src_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open source file %s\n", src_filename);
        return 1; 
    }
    // rest of code 
}
```

the error received by `avformat_open_input` is `Permission Denied`. I cannot even open a random text file in this function by doing:

```
ofstream output; 
output.open("output.txt");
```

I realize there are file system permissions that are blocking the C++ component of my uwp app from opening files. here are the things i have tried so far:

- i have enabled broadFileSystemAccess in the Package.appxmanifest (https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2018/05/18/console-uwp-applications-and-file-system-access/) - in the Capabilities section of the Package.appxmanifest file I've allowed access to Location, Pictures Library, and Videos Library.
- I've checked the File System Privacy Settings on my computer and enabled my app to access the File System.
- I've tried moving the mp4 file to various locations (Documents, Pictures Library, Videos Library) to see if the C++ component has access to these locations.
- I've tried the solution from this post: [Qt WinRT App cannot access file permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35551995/qt-winrt-app-cannot-access-file-permission-denied).

None of these allow the C++ component to open any files. i would really appreciate if anyone has a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `broadFileSystemAccess` capability gives you access to the full file system, but not for all APIs, only for the UWP's `Windows.Storage` API. This means you have to use `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile` to access the file. For example, you can then retrieve the file [from a given path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync?view=winrt-19041) with `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync`.

Comment: i'm having a problem opening the file from the C++ windows runtime component, not from UWP.

Comment: That is fine, C++ Windows Runtime Component has full access to the UWP API set. See the answer from @YanGu - MSFT

Answer (score 0):

The **Windows Runtime Componnet C++** project is a **Universal Windows** project(UWP project). You could see the characters **(Universal Windows)** in the left of your component project name in the **Solution Explorer**.

For a UWP project(including Windows Runtime Componnet C++ project), you could access certain file system locations by default such as application install directory, application data locations, user’s downloads folder, or [access libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-managing-folders-in-the-music-pictures-and-videos-libraries) by [declaring capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations), or let the user pick files and folders by [calling a file picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers), referring to the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) document. If you need to read and write a file using a StorageFile object, you could refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files).

For example, if your `mp4` file is in **Videos** library, you could use the following code to get a file:

1. Add the **Videos** capability in your C# UWP project’s manifest.
2. Check the code as a sample:

```
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Storage.Search.h>

using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Search;

……
auto lib =co_await Windows::Storage::StorageLibrary::GetLibraryAsync(Windows::Storage::KnownLibraryId::Videos);
auto folder = lib.Folders().GetAt(0);
StorageFile myMp4 =co_await folder.GetFileAsync(L"test.mp4");
```

If you need the C++ code of other ways such as accessing the default locations or access files by calling pickers, please feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

it's not because of the file you picked from the user.
this error can happen because of the following 2 Case

1. since FFmpeg Api Uses Syncronus file Access system and uwp Does not Support that in the file system except the Apps Local Directory, so you can do that by first copying the file picked by the user to Local Folder and then using a copied file to access the file.
2. due to the dll required to access API during runtime, so you have to Add All Dll to the main folder where you have App.xaml and then set the property to content and copy always to all dll

i.e.avcodec,avdevice,avfilter,avformat,avresample,avutil,postproc,swresample,swscale

read this: "Windows Store Certification, File I/O, and Other Details" - at http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT